# NPAPI flash plugin for usage with node-webkit

Tags: flash, npapi, node-webkit

I'm trying to pack my web-app to all major OS (win+mac+linux) using node-webkit (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit).

My problem is with the NPAPI flash plugin. Currently it is being phased out by google and others, so I can't find a place to get it for all (or any) platforms (for win it's a DLL, mac it's something else etc.).

I have to use Flash for some features of the app.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about one specific topic per "question", so you should split the second one off. I think the first question is off-topic as it is not strictly a coding issue.

Comment: I agree that the question could be split to two, but the second question has no value without the files in hand, which I can't seem to find... So I preferred having them together. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is still two separate issues - them being interdependent doesn't change things. Stackoverflow only works well when questions/issues are well separated (e.g. may get answered by completely different people).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the needed files in an early version of chrome (version 18.XXX to be more specific).

You should download the version for each platform you need and get the plugins from the installed version folder.

Comment: Using a Flash plugin that's 2 years old means using a plugin that has known security vulnerabilities, so is a very bad idea.

Comment: You are correct, it was actually changed by Google back then because of security issues of this whole NPAPI protocol...
But eventually, node-webkit flash is based on that plugin, and they state at their Wiki that the DO NOT support the replacement of this protocol (Pepper API - [link](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Third-party-browser-plugins#supported-plugins)).
So, do you see a better solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you want the NPAPI Flash plugin, you should get it from the vendor: Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

The Flash player is made by Adobe, so I'm not sure what "phased out by Google and others" means here; whether or not a specific browser supports NPAPI has nothing to do with actually getting the NPAPI plugin from Adobe.

If you're looking for a copy of the Flash player, you should use the [download page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) for it.